# Как в Sublime Text 3 изменить шрифт текста в Side Bar?

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Здравствуйте! Как изменить шрифт текста в панели `Side Bar` в `Sublime Text 3`? Т.е. там, где показываются открытые папки и файлы проектов. Изменение системного шрифта ничего не даёт.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

За текст сайдбара в `Sublime Text 3` отвечает класс `sidebar_label`.

<kbd>Preferences</kbd> → <kbd>Browse Paskages</kbd> → <kbd>User</kbd>, создаём файл ***Default.sublime-theme***, если он ещё не создан, и между `[]` вставляем в него следующий код:

```
    // Текст сайдбара
    {
        "class": "sidebar_label",
        "font.face":"Trebuchet MS",
        "font.size":14,
        "color": [205, 92, 92, 255],
    },
```

Свойства:

- `font.face` — шрифт. Если в имени шрифта содержится пробел, то вводить его  клавишей <kbd>space</kbd>, не используя подчерк `_` ;
- `font.size` — размер шрифта;
- `color` — цвет текста в [RGBA](http://cuprum.name/page/cvetovaya-model-rgba).

[image: Цвет текста в сайдбаре Sublime Text 3]

Спасибо.